# secure id value in mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have table for example

```
  table Car(
   id int primary key,
   type nvarchar(300)
)
```

and I have mvc CarController
with

```
[Httpost]
Edit(Car model){}
```

I have view where Id is hidden and type is texbox, now I would like to know If someone overides the hidden value and sends another Id, doesn't it changes another row? how can I prevent this?

Comment: you can store the id in Session before returning the View

Comment: Or in server cache, but I think a better solution will be to check if the user can modify the object or not

Answer (score 1):

For this following is the best solution where you have to prevent id.

1. Use antiforgery token (it will not help in this case but will cover
   most of other case).
2. Encrypt your Id value before sending it to view. When post happens try
       to decrypt it and check that it decrypts properly. If an error was
       thrown during decryption then it got edited by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to disable edit some entities? May be it would be better to create some permission system. For example, you can include *OwnerId* to the *Car* entity and after retrieving *Car* by *Id* check that current (logged in) user is owner of this car.